# SQLiteResult::numColumns returning 1 when the database is empty (PHP)

Tags: php, sql, database, sqlite

I'll start this by saying that I am very new to SQLite (this is basically my first time properly trying it out), but I am familiar with SQL via MySQL and have used that plenty.

I have verified that my SQLite 3 database is working using a program called "DB Browser For SQLite".  Right now it's empty, and I'm testing a user sign up system.  I'm trying to do a check where I take the e-mail and username provided and check them against the database to confirm they haven't already been used by counting the returned rows.  Seeing as my database is empty at the moment, I would expect a result of 0 regardless of what I submit, but I keep getting a result of 1.

```
$db = new SQLite3('database.db');

$email = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['email']);
$username = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST['username']);

// check if email already exists
$email_query = $db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1;");
$email_exists = $email_query->numColumns();

// check if username already exists
$username_query = $db->query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1;");
$username_exists = $username_query->numColumns();
```

When I run those queries in "DB Browser For SQLite", I get the expected results.  I'm not getting any PHP errors either.  My one theory is that the `1` that is being returned by `numColumns()` is actually error code 1, but when I use `SQLite3::lastErrorCode()`, I get 0, meaning no errors.  I'm lost...would really love some insight here!

Comment: So fetch result and see it

Comment: You should be counting the number of *rows*, not the number of columns. The number of columns is just the number of fields you specified in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of columns is just the number of fields you requested. If you had done `SELECT username, email ...` it would have returned `2` because you selected 2 columns.

If you want to know if there are any matches, you should count the number of *rows*, not columns. But the `SQLite3` extension doesn't provide a `numRows` method. You could change your query so you do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

and then see whether `$row['count']` is greater than 0. Or you could use your existing query and try to fetch the result.

```
$email_exists = !empty($email_query->fetchArray());
```

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot.  I was looking for the equivalent of `mysqli_num_rows`, and I saw "num" and didn't even realize it said "column" this whole time.  I'm so dumb -.- thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

When there are no rows, `numColumns()` will return 1. The solution, is to do this:

```
if ($username_query->numColumns() && $username_query->columnType(0) != SQLITE3_NULL) {
    // Rows exist
} else {
    // No data
}
```

Credit goes to [Jon Scully](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php#94873).

Other comments suggest though that `columnType` may *always* return `SQLITE3_NULL`, and to instead do this to determine if there are rows:

```
if ($result->fetchArray()[0] == null) {
   // No rows
}
```

Comment: I think that's probably fixed it, I'm getting different behavior now at least.  I can't check it right this second, but thanks for the info!  I was definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: numColumns() is a metadata function and its value is determined by the query code and not by the query results. The original answer (top of the post) is misleading and should be removed. I'll remove my comment after that.

Comment: Makes sense. Explains why the `fetchArray` is a better approach to figuring out if there are rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
$email_query = $db->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1;");
if($email_query->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
    //email exists
}
```